# XPathNavigator can't find nodes despite XmlNamespaceManager

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xpathnavigator

I hate to ask yet another XPath/XmlNamespaceManager question, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I used XpathVisualizer tool which can correctly detect the node using XPath "//FuelGradeMovement". It recognized the namespaces and evaluated the XPath just like that.

I only want to check if the node "**FuelGradeMovement**" exists. Easy enough. But no, doesn't work.

**Clearly the node I am xpath'ing doesn't even have a prefix, but if I don't use the namespace manager I get a runtime error, as other nodes in the document do have prefixes.**

**And with the namespace it just doesn't see the node for some reason.**

I am trying to parse this document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<NAXML-MovementReport version="3.4" xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16" xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16 NAXML-PBI34RadiantExtended.xsd">
    <TransmissionHeader>....
    </TransmissionHeader>
    <FuelGradeMovement/>
</NAXML-MovementReport>
```

using this code:

```
    using ( var fs = file.OpenRead() )
{
    var x = new XPathDocument( fs );

    var nav = x.CreateNavigator();
    var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager( nav.NameTable );

    mgr.AddNamespace( "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" );
    mgr.AddNamespace( "xmime", "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" );
    mgr.AddNamespace( "radiant", "http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension" );
    mgr.AddNamespace( "ns1", "http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16" );

    var iterator = nav.Select( "//FuelGradeMovement", mgr );

    return iterator.Count > 0;
}
```

I tried so many combinations but I don't see my mistake.
Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifiying the namespace manager - but not the namespace. The `FuelGradeMovement` element has inherited the `"http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16"` namespace URI from its parent, so I believe you want:

```
var iterator = nav.Select("//ns1:FuelGradeMovement", mgr);
```

Just because the element doesn't *specify* a namespace prefix doesn't mean it's not in a namespace.

Note that unless you really want complicated XPath queries, LINQ to XML makes all of this a lot simpler. For example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fs);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16";
return doc.Descendants(ns + "FuelGradeMovement").Any();
```

Comment: thanks you are right. How could I do this with LINQ? IS there a way to "ignore" the namespaces with LINQ-XML? Thank you!

Comment: @John: Why would you ignore them? You'd just use the right namespace... you *could* ignore the namespace, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I have a few large documents I need to parse, some of them have namespaces and some of them don't, but the only difference is the NS declaration in the root. The node names don't have prefixes. I'd need to format all the XPaths to either include or exclude the NS.

Comment: @John: Then you *could* use `doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == ...)` - but it would be cleaner if you could just normalize the documents if possible...